# Refresh with localStorage and Multiple Logins

Tags: angularjs

I am developing a angular app in which i need to give refresh ability to user. Using the localStorage i can get login details of the user. But if i login with another user in new tab then it override the login details of previous user.

So my question is that can we keep the localStorage tab wise?

Answer (score 0):

Use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage):

> sessionStorage is similar to Window.localStorage, the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives
>   over page reloads and restores. **Opening a page in a new tab or window
>   will cause a new session to be initiated**, which differs from how
>   session cookies work.

Comment: I want to give refresh functionality to user. That's why sessionStorage will not work in that case.

Comment: What do you mean by refresh functionality? If you mean that the data survives browsers page refresh then you are wrong:"A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores."

Comment: You're welcome :) So feel free to accept the answer ;)